# assign JS variable value to razor variable

Tags: javascript, razor

```
<button type="submit" onclick="add(x)"id="add-button" >ADD </button>

<script>
function add(x){
@{
var iWantValueOfxAssignedToThisSomehow=(something)x;
}
}
</script>
```

I already tried:

```
var iWantValueOfxAssignedToThisSomehow=@:x;
and var iWantValueOfxAssignedToThisSomehow=<text>x</text>;
```

I also read few comments about it saying its not possible since they don't live on the same time. I was wondering if there were other way around?

Comment: If you want your variable in C#, you'll have to have your function post that value to the server.

Comment: ok is there any way other that isPost(). I can't use isPost() because it reloads my page. Or is there any way I could use isPost and not reload my page? I have searched everywhere

Comment: Use AJAX, e.g. jQuery.ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: care to explain how?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before so it is possible, from memory you should be able to do any of the below as long as it's on a .cshtml page

```
function myFunction(){
    var value1 = @Model.Value
    var value2 = @(3)
    var value3 = @("Value as a hard coded string")
    //3 examples of how you assign a C# variable to a js variable
}
```

Just tested and this method works fine.

To clarify why yours wasn't working: You were assigning the variable `iWantValueOfxAssignedToThisSomehow` in memory when the page is complied in C# but you never assigned it to anything in js, hence the function should be blank when rendered.

As for the comments you have read about; They are talking about how the C# variable is only every assigned once it is assigned and it cannot be changed by js since at that point it is off the server which is where the C# is executed.

Edit: While the above is valid it was not what you were looking for, it is not possible to pass JS variables into C# since C# is run Server side and JS is run Client Side

Comment: Can you make it a little simple for me please? I am new to all these :/ Can you show me how to do it in my code?

Comment: @Nick In the example above I show you can you assign a js var from a C# var from either a Model or from a hardcoded var. Simply replace what I have after the @ with whatever var from c# you need to assign but note that for a inline int or string you need to use the `@()` syntax as shown above

Comment: So, where do I put function myFunction{..} and how does my variable iWantValueOfXassignedToThisSomehow gets the value of x that is passed by onClick function?

Comment: You can pass your variable into JS just as you have, by having x as a parameter in the function, but you cannot then pass it into C#, you can only assign variables from C# to js but you cannot pass anything from js into C# since C# is Rendered Server side and JS is run Client side

Comment: BTW I want to assign a JS variable to a razor variable not the other way around.

Comment: @Nick Right, my bad, I misinterpreted what you were asking. In that case as my previous comment it's not possible